# how to get all strings between nth occurance with 2 different pattern

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, case-when

i have table, one of the field has value like this :

```
LLC1R.8888.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*CNY*ARTIST*
TC1R.88.GR0054656*DR.765012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*LUKE*
K56R.8.GR0054656*DR.258812...4..............GR0054656*AUD*
790GG.88.GR0054656*DR.338012...5..............GR0054656*IDR*MATTHEW*
GREFD.888.GR0054656*DR.198012...6..............GR0054656*
```

Expexcting result :

```
ARTIST

LUKE

MATTHEW
```

How to extract between 3rd and 4th and make the other column safe, because the result will be use in `case when` ?

Any ideas/help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, '^(?:[^*]*\\*){3}([^*]*)', 1)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^*]*\*){3}` - three occurrences of any chars other than `*` and then a `*` char
- `([^*]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `*`.

The *index* argument is set to `1` so as to extract Group 1 value.

Note that `(?:[^*]*\*)` is a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) that does not capture (store in a separate memory buffer) the substring it matches.

Comment: @thecardcaptor did you use ``\\`` before `*`?

Comment: sorry i was not using ?: it went great.

Comment: how about extracting the currency like CNY, EUR, AUD, IDR?

Comment: @thecardcaptor Replace `{3}` with `{2}`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2QDqXC/1).